# Only match single word when using negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript I'm currently using the regular expression:

```
/^(?!3838\s+REGATTA\s+COURT).*(COURT).*/
```

I want to entirely avoid matching:

> 3838 REGATTA COURT

And match:(the addresses will be vary)

> 5555 REGATTA COURT

However, I only want to match the word "COURT" and not the entire string(which is what my current expression returns).

Also, 5555 REGATTA COURT cannot be removed by specifying an expression such as ^(?!5555\s+REGATTA\s+COURT) because the addresses will vary. I essentially need to avoid matching everything up to "COURT" and then match it.

Comment: Well your current pattern in fact _does_ capture the word `COURT`.  But, I don't even see the point of that, because if your pattern matches, then you already know it contains `COURT`.

Comment: I need to eventually use a replace function to replace the word "COURT" with "CT" for most addresses when searching a database, but not for those few addresses that have "COURT" as part of the name (COURT is abbreviated to CT for most addresses in the database). So, the regular expression needs to capture the word "COURT" by itself so as to not replace the entire string. It's based on user input so that when "COURT" is inputted it is automatically replaced with "CT" except for cases in which the address itself contains the word "COURT" written in long form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about the use of $1...$9 in the replacement string, simply check the MDN documentation for the standardized way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter. The code would then be:

```
var address = "5555 REGATTA COURT ";
var output = address.replace(/^(?!3838\s+REGATTA\s+COURT\b)(.*)\bCOURT\b(.*)/, function(m, g1, g2) { return g1 + "CT" + g2; });
console.log(address);
console.log(output);
```

However, the MDN article you mentioned in the comments also has a compatibility chart, which shows that the string syntax is also supported by all modern (and not so modern) browsers.

Comment: That is why I upvoted your answer and even filed a flag to share the rep with you, since you did the heavy work. I'll check how the bounty works and transfer the gained rep to you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Looks like bounties can only be placed on questions, not on answers, although the moderator told me, I should share the rep this way. Anyways, I believe in giving credit, where credit is due. Since you have updated your answer to also include my addition about using the function syntax, I'll be happy to delete my answer, when OP changes to accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using a regex replace all:

```js
var address = "5555 REGATTA COURT ";
var output = address.replace(/^(?!3838\s+REGATTA\s+COURT\b)(.*)\bCOURT\b(.*)/, "$1CT$2");
console.log(address);
console.log(output);
```

The logic here is to first exclude the address `3838 REGATTA COURT`.  Then, match and capture everything on either side of the word `COURT`.  Finally, replace with the two capture groups with `CT` in between them.

We can also try doing this using a callback function:

```js
var address = "5555 REGATTA COURT ";
var output = address.replace(/^(?!3838\s+REGATTA\s+COURT\b)(.*)\bCOURT\b(.*)/, function(m, g1, g2) { return g1 + "CT" + g2; });
console.log(address);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, it worked! Jquery? I'm not familiar with the $1 $2 syntax used in this instance. Thanks for your help.  I've been on this for two days.

Comment: @Mr.J `$1` and `$2` are just the first and second capture groups, respectively.  In this case, they are everything which came before `COURT` and everything which came after `COURT`.

Comment: Is there cause for concern when using capture groups? There was a message on MDN saying they shouldn't be used in production: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n

Comment: Sorry, about the lack of a checkmark.  I tried to upvote it, but I don't have enough kudos, so the site won't let me.

Comment: @Mr.J I didn't read that article, but capture groups are very much a part of the JavaScript regex API, and there is nothing inherently wrong with using them, so long as the accompanying regex pattern is well written and regex is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry about that.  This is my first post. It's checked!